# Create new instance of object based on variable

Tags: php, variables

I'm trying to create an instance of an object but the object class name is set by hand.

in config.php:

```
define('DIRECTORY', 'RaptorDirectory');
```

in the class file:

```
$this->directory = new DIRECTORY; // <--- how do I use the constant there?
```

I'm doing this because DIRECTORY might change to a different class (e.g., LDAPDirectory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a constant there but you can use a variable, eg

```
$class = DIRECTORY;
$this->directory = new $class;
```

Comment: thanks. will just switch to a variable i guess. is this documented?

Comment: @davidosomething http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#example-157